# Power BI: How to return values from one table based on slicers referencing another table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling, measure

I have a Power BI report with two tables in it. Table_1 looks like this:

| ID | Country | Cost | Joining_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAR23 | UK | 20 | MAR23_UK |
| MAR23 | ROI | 10 | MAR23_ROI |
| JAN23 | UK | 25 | JAN23_UK |
| JAN23 | ROI | 25 | JAN23_ROI |

Joining_field is a calculated column which is always unique.

Table_2 looks like this:

| Customer | ID | Country | Year | Month | Joining_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | MAR23 | UK | 2023 | MAR | MAR23_UK |
| Y | MAR23 | UK | 2023 | MAR | MAR23_UK |
| Z | MAR23 | ROI | 2023 | MAR | MAR23_ROI |
| X | JAN23 | UK | 2023 | JAN | JAN23_UK |
| Y | JAN23 | ROI | 2023 | JAN | JAN23_ROI |

Joining_field is a calculated column which is not unique.

The two tables have a 1 to many relationship using the joining field in both tables.

On the front page of my report I have three slicers, which filter on the Country, Year, and Month fields from table_2.

I want to create a measure in table_2 which returns the value from the cost column in table_1 based on the values selected in the slicers. So in the example above, if the slicers are set to Country = UK, Year = 2023, and Month = MAR, then the measure should return 20.

I've tried the following DAX without success; it appears to just be summing up the entirety of the Cost column from table_1:

```
Measure_1 =
VAR V_year = SELECTEDVALUE(table_2[Year])
VAR V_month = SELECTEDVALUE(table_2[Month])
VAR V_country = SELECTEDVALUE(table_2[Country])
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(table_1[Cost]),USERELATIONSHIP(table_2[Joining_field],table_1[Joining_field]), 
table_2[Year] = V_year, 
table_2[Month] = V_month, 
table_2[Country] = V_country)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can achieve the required result please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following measure.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(Table_1[Cost]), CROSSFILTER(Table_1[Joining_field], Table_2[Joining_field], Both))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, but could you explain what it's doing, why it works when userelationship doesn't, and why it works without specifying the values the slicers are set to please?

Comment: Sure but I think you're missing some basic  PBI knowledge. You have a relationship set up but the filter direction is uni-directional. Setting crossfilter to both ensures the relationship can propagate in the opposite direction for the measure. You can achieve the same by setting bi-directional filters in your model but this is not advised. Userelationship() is only for when you have multiple defined relationships and want to pick the correct one for your measure.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I'm definitely a PBI rookie. Just to confirm: It sounds like the uni-directional relationship can't filter table_1 by table_2, but it could hypothetically filter table_2 by table_1. And the relationship presumably points in that direction because table_1 is the one in the relationship and table 2 is the many. So if I want a measure to filter the one by the many, I need to use crossfilter to specify that I want the relationship to work both ways while calculating the measure. Is that all correct?

Comment: That's right, yes